# Pass data with asynchronous method from a service to a component Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

i am working in a Login method in my service that passes data to components when the user login the app. This login method makes a http request and in case of success, it calls the setAuthentication method to update the properties i want to share.

But when i want to use this properties in a component, for example a dashboard page with the name of the user, using

```
  public currentUser = this.authService.currentUser
```

I am not getting the updated property values, just null.

This is my service code:

```
  public currentUserAuth:User | null =  null
  public currentUser:User | null =  null
  public currentState:authStatus = authStatus.Cheking
  

  public loginUser(loginInterface: loginInterface){
    const url = `${this.basicURL}/login`
    const body = {email: loginInterface.email, password1: loginInterface.password1}
    return this.http.post<loginResponse>(url, body)
    .pipe
    (map(({user, token, currentUser}) => this.setAuthentication(user, token, currentUser!)),
    catchError(err => throwError(() => err.error.message))
    )
  }

  public setAuthentication(userPayload:User, token:string, currentUser: User){
    this.currentUserAuth = userPayload
    this.currentState = authStatus.Authenticated
    this.currentUser = currentUser
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
    
    return true
  }
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: You are likely accessing currentUser prior to setAuthentication running.  Did you check the value of currentState when the error occurs?

Comment: I think tis is the problem. CurrentState works, it changes to authenticated. But how do i access to currentUser after setAuthentication? I tried with getter method as suggested in the answer but now i am getting undefined instead of null

Answer (score 0):

Please change `currentUser` to a getter method instead

```
public get currentUser(): any {
    return this.authService.currentUser;
}
```

If you dont like using getter methods, then you need to set the property of currentUser only after the value is set in the service, below I am assuming currentUser in the service is set before the ngoninit runs!

```
public currentUser;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentUser = this.authService.currentUser;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i tried both, can you read my answer in the comments section of the question?

Comment: @Bayes-T please share a stackblitz with the new error, ensure the service has the property providedIn 'root' so that the service only has one copy that is shared, also you need to null check everywhere you use this property, example: current user && current user.test